# How to set data type of Arraylist<String> in hibernate annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, arraylist

I want to set the data type of Arraylist when it was saved into the database. 
For example:
I use annotation for String variable and when it was saved into database, the data type of it is TEXT

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
String matKhau;
```

So, I don't know any way to do the same things with ArrayList like:

```
@CollectionOfElements
//add some annotation to set data type in here
ArrayList<String> ghiChu = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Because I save Vietnamese String into the database, so it has charset=UTF-8, but when I try this code above, it saved and data type is BLOG, and that's problem. I want to change the BLOG to LONGTEXT, so what should I do for this issue? Sorry, my bad Eng.

Comment: Don't use concrete types as variables generally, and *definitely* don't use them with JPA; use `List<String>` instead. Most JPA providers will use dynamic proxies to substantially improve performance and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `@CollectionOfElements` (it's already deprecated). Use JPA's `@ElementCollection`. You can use the same `@Column` annotation to specify column definition for your collection of basic types such as `String`.

So here's a sample.

```
@ElementCollection
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
List<String> ghiChu = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: I've tried to use your instruction but when I run this test below, it send me an error: Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr...' for column 'ghiChu' at row 1. The test is:
ArrayList<String> string = new ArrayList<String>();
string.add("this is a test, do not give me any error plz");
TestList test = new TestList();
test.setId("02");
test.setGhiChu(string);
TestListDAO.saveOrUpdate(test);

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it successes by changes @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB") and uses @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class) in this class where I push the get method and I feel satisfied for this.

Comment: You won't need to specify targetClass if you are using generics.